# Why doesn't WCF Service Reference keep some settings after metadata exchange?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

I'm defining a binding like this in my WCF Service's `app.config` file:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1"
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             transactionFlow="false"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             listenBacklog="10"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxBufferSize="524288"
             maxConnections="10"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="524288">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                    maxStringContentLength="8192"
                    maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true"
                       inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                       enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Note that I have set `maxBufferSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` to be 524288 bytes.  In my client project, when I click "Add Service Reference" I am able to discover and add my service.  But it fills out my client's `app.config` file like this

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_AgileService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I'm curious why `maxBufferSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` have reverted back to their defaults in my client's `app.config`.  Do these settings apply separately to the client and server?  In other words, can the client and server each have their own message size limits?

Is there anything else that I need to do on the client to make sure that the client will be willing to send messages of 524288 bytes? (I only care about client -> server communication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the settings are specific to the client or the server (depending on which config you're dealing with).  `MaxReceivedMessageSize` applies only to the size of the message being received by the service or the client, not the size of the message being sent.

You may neeed to increase `MaxStringContentLength` in the `ReaderQuotas` as well to handle a larger message.  Also, you'll need to make sure you reference your Binding1 configuration in your endpoint on your service (via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute) in your service's config file, otherwise your service will revert to the default settings for NetTcpBinding.

Example:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
              contract="MyService.IMyContract" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Great answer - very helpful information about MaxStringContentLength

Answer (score 0):

Notice the name of MaxReceivedMessageSize. Its about the size of the data the **receiver** of the data is prepared to accept. It is, therefore, likely that the client and service will want different values - so these are not part of the generated values from the metadata